# Problem with changing value of multiple rows to NaN

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, for-loop, nan

I have this DataFrame:

```
test = database[['WEATHER']]
```

[image]

Some of the values of WEATHER are "Unknown" and "Other", which don't bring much value to it so I want to change them to NaN. Thus, I try the following code:

```
for i in range(len(test)):
if test['WEATHER'][i] == "Other" or test['WEATHER'][i] == "Unknown":
    test['WEATHER'][i] = np.nan
```

And this error keeps appearing:

[image]

I have been trying to correct it but I haven't found the way to.

Comment: Why dont you try `df.replace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stack trace contains *KeyError: 15*, so probably you attempt to
retrieve row with key == just *15*, but your DataFrame does not contain
such a key.

And now how to properly and efficiently do your task.
Use *mask* on the column in question, with *inplace*:

```
df.WEATHER.mask(df.WEATHER.str.lower().isin(['other', 'unknown']), np.nan, inplace=True)
```

To provide proper handling regardless of letter casing (e.g. *other* or
*OTHER*), I convert original values to lower case an then compare with
a "forbidden" list.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you want to avoid iterating over a pandas `DataFrame`. Here is how I would do it:

```
>>> df.a
0      Other
1    Unknown
2       BLAH
Name: a, dtype: object
>>> df.a = np.choose(df.a.isin(['Other', 'Unknown']), [df.a, np.nan])
>>> df.a
0     NaN
1     NaN
2    BLAH
Name: a, dtype: object
```

`isin()` checks if each value is in the predefined list `['Other', 'Unknown']` and `np.choose()` attributes a value depending on the boolean result of the call to `isin()`. The result is either the original value `df.a` or `np.nan`.